# How can I determine maximum X and maximum Y of flutter screen?

Tags: flutter

I try to find maximum x and maximum y of screen size by height and width and below image and code.

Expected Output

[image]

```
Path drawPath(){
        double width = window.physicalSize.width;
        double height = window.physicalSize.height;
        Path path = Path();
        path.moveTo(0,0);
        path.lineTo(width, height);
        return path;
  }
```

Getting Output

[image]

So how can I find Maximum X and Maximum Y in flutter screen  ?

Expected output(not perfect but approx.) getting by this code.

```
Path drawPath(){
            double width = window.physicalSize.width;
            double height = window.physicalSize.height;
            Path path = Path();
            path.moveTo(0,0);
            path.lineTo(width/2, height/2); //need to divide by 2
            return path;
      }
```

Comment: I don't understand your diagram where you are going off the screen.  How do you know there's anything painted off the screen?

Comment: I animated my widget on this path. by the changing of x y value , I figured this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the `BuildContext`, you can retrieve width and height such as:

```dart
final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

Or if you don't:

```dart
import 'dart:ui';

final double width = window.physicalSize.width / window.devicePixelRatio;
final double height = window.physicalSize.height / window.devicePixelRatio;
```